# How to get Flow Radio Buttons to have a horizontal layout?

Tags: visual-workflow, radio-button

I have some `Radio Button` which use a `Picklist Choice Set` inside a `Flow`.

The `Picklist Choice Set` has 10 options, which means it uses up a lot of vertical space.

Is there any way to make a `Radio Button` layout in horizontally in a `Flow`?

Comment: Not possible with OOTB Flow Screen Components. Create a custom lightning component and use it inside the flow screen.

Comment: see https://sfdcmonkey.com/2018/08/03/radio-button-group-horizontal-view/ for an example